# Angular - Can't access directives scope when directive is injected outside of Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am injecting Angular markup from within a jQuery plugin (got the idea from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/umidjons/1fb8ae674df4c71f85cf)):

```
var $place = this.$el.find('.medium-insert-active');
Angular.element($place).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
    var scope = Angular.element(document.getElementById('editor-container')).scope();
    $place.html($('<quiz/>'));
    var quiz = $compile($place.contents())(scope);
    scope.$digest();
});
```

Here is the `quiz` directive:

```
const quiz = {
    controller: QuizController,
    controllerAs: 'qm',
    template: require('./quiz.html'),
}
```

This successfully compiles my directive into the DOM and instantiates a `QuizController`.

I am wondering how to access the `scope` (and `QuizController`) of my `quiz` directive.

I thought it would be `quiz.scope()` but this gives the scope contained within the `scope` variable.

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gBf6yoS5UugaZEKLcNqI?p=preview).

Comment: I ask as `QuizController` fetches data from a server including an id which I need to interact with programatically.

Comment: Can you share a plunker..in order to help you out in a better manner

Comment: Added a plunker

Answer (score 0):

I was creating an isolate scope as I was creating a `component`. If I instead create a `directive` without an isolate scope, the controller is attached to the scope that was passed into the linking function returned by `$compile`.